# Create pivot table using KornShell

Tags: shell, csv, ksh, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot table (csv) using KornShell (ksh).

**This is the data (csv):**

```
name       a1  a2     amount
----------------------------
product1 | 1 | 1000 |  1.5
product1 | 2 | 2000 |  2.6
product1 | 3 | 3000 |  1.2
product1 | 1 | 3000 |  2.1  
product1 | 2 | 3000 |  4.1
product1 | 3 | 2000 |  3.1
```

**The result should be:**

```
__| a2| 1000 | 2000 | 3000
a1 \----------------------  
1  |    1.5           2.1
2  |           2.6    4.1
3  |           3.1    1.2
```

I want to "group" the data by the two attributes and create a table which contains the sums of the amount column for the respective attributes.

**EDIT**: The attributes a1 and a2 are dynamic. I do not know which one of them is going to exist and which not, or how many attributes there will be at all.

Comment: What are your attempts?

Comment: I want to summarize the output of an sql query. The query is generating a long list containing the values described above (name, a1, a2, amount). I want to summarize this output by generating a table. y-axis is representing a1, and the x-axis is representing a2. The cells are representing the sums of the amount for the corresponding a1 and a2.

Comment: Yes, yes, I understand the requirement :) I just want to indicate that to get an answer it is good to show what you have programmed so far.

Comment: Sure, so far I am doing the naive approach where I "generate" columns using Sql, and I am restricting the output to certain values: SUM(CASE WHEN a1 = 1 THEN amount END) ...
In the end there is a column to capture anything not in the CASE WHEN condition.
I would like to implement it in a more dynamic way. I am not looking for a copy-paste solution! Maybe shell isn't the best way to handle this problem. Do you think perl or python would be better suited?

Comment: How can you do this if you don't know how many attributes there will be? As I see it, you need exactly three attributes (one each for X and Y columns, and one for the content)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are not using the database as effectively as you might.  Here is a thought to help you make some headway: You can generate SQL using the shell.

You know what the beginning of each query is going to look like:

```
select a1,
```

So you would want to start building some report SQL:

```
Report_SQL="select a1, "
```

You then would need to get the list of SQL statements for an arbitrarily sized set of columns for the pivot report(in MySQL - Other databases would require `||` concatenation):

```
select distinct concat('sum(case a2 when ', a2, ' then amount else null end) as "_', a2,'",')
  from my_database_table
 order by 1
;
```

Because this is in the shell, it is easy to pull this into a variable as follows:

```
SQL=" select distinct concat('sum(case a2 when ', a2, ' then amount else null end) as _', a2,',') "
SQL+="  from my_database_table "
SQL+=" order by 1 "

# You would have to define a runsql command for your database platform.
a2_columns=$(runsql "$SQL")
```

At this point you will have an extra comma at the end of the `a2_columns` variable.  That is easily removed:

```
a2_columns=${a2_columns%,}
```

Now we can concatenate these variables to create the report SQL that you really seem to need:

```
Report_SQL+="${a2_columns}"
Report_SQL+="  from my_database_table "
Report_SQL+=" group by 1"
Report_SQL+=" order by 1"
```

The resulting report SQL would look something like this:

```
select a1,  
       sum(case a2 when 1000 then amount else null end) as _1000,
       sum(case a2 when 2000 then amount else null end) as _2000,
       sum(case a2 when 3000 then amount else null end) as _3000
  from my_database_table
 group by 1
 order by 1
;
```

The formatting of the report header is left as an exercise to the reader. :)

Comment: Hi Gabe. Thank you for your thorough answer. I like your approach.

I currently ended up using a small perl script for the transponation. However, I will try our approach, because it's very handy.